# Out of Memory when using DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

I was trying to open edit a 225MB `.sql` file in **DataGrip**, but it opens part of it as a read-only. After that, whenever I click the File panel it returns **"Out of Memory"**.

I've already reinstall and delete the folder `C:\Users\***\.DataGrip2018.3`, yet the problem exist.

[image: DataGrip]

Comment: Does it show that error on a smaller .sql file? Culprit is more than likely the sheer size of that file.

Comment: By now this window will come out when I click File button and I have nothing opened.

Comment: Unfortunately it takes a lot of resources to analyse all your sql. On screenshot DataGrip showed you dialog where you can increase memory that is allocated for it. Did you try to change 750MB to e.g. 1500MB?

Comment: Another option is to split your big file into multiple smaller files

Comment: Did you try to replace that big file and then open DataGrip? Anyway, logs to datagrip@jetbrains.com will be useful.

Comment: I set it to 4096MB that the problem solved. But no file opened! And the animation is not smooth at all. After I restart the system the problem finally gone. Thanks you guys. I'll feedback it.

Comment: If you want to run a long file without opening, please use Context Menu -> Run...